# List of plugins was not loaded android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to install plugin in android studio when I Click Browse Respository it Shows this dialog  [image]

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the alternative solution, just delete the .AndroidStudio foler, and restart androi studio.

using

```
rm -R .AndroidStudio
```

After that the android studio back to default settings and install the plugin from the beginning

Answer (score 1):

Check permissions on /root/.AndroidStudio to confirm you can create the directory for plugins.

Simple way to modify permissions for User(u), Group(g) and Other(o) from command line:

chmod -R ugo+rw /root/.AndroidStudio/

Comment: well i'm new to Linux so maybe you could give me more explanation,like step by step, thanks

Comment: I tried to change the permission in terminal on the plugins location, using chmod but doesn't work

Comment: doesn't work?  what error did it give you when changing permissions?  or are you stating that the original issue still exists after changing permissions?